# EJS sort filter doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ejs

Really appreciate some help in saving my hair that's left. I'm building a basic CRUD application using node.js + express + mongoDB + EJS. I gotta say, EJS has terrible documentation, making it really hard for us newbies to learn it. Here's the problem that I'm having.

I have an object called "vehicles" and I'm displaying it in a form select element. Here's my EJS:

```
<% vehicles.forEach(function(el){ %>
   <option value="<%= el.vehicleModel %>"><%= el.vehicleModel %></option>
<% }); %>
```

Problem is, because it's picking up from object passed by MongoDB, it's not sorted. I went Googling and found [this nice tutorial](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=4241). EJS has filters that's (supposed) to solve this problem. So I tried the following code:

```
<% vehicles.forEach(function(el){ %>
    <option value="<%=: el.vehicleModel | sort %>"><%=: el.vehicleModel | sort %></option>
<% }); %>
```

But it throws me the following error:

Object prototype may only be an Object or null

So I thought something was wrong with my code. I tinkered it with another filter (downcase) and used it like this:

```
<% vehicles.forEach(function(el){ %>
    <option value="<%=: el.vehicleModel | downcase %>"><%=: el.vehicleModel | downcase %></option>
<% }); %>
```

And it works. The characters are undercased. Then why is the sort filter not working?

P/S: There goes another hair of mine..

Comment: I know this question is solved, but you should stop using filters as they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort filter takes an array as input, not a string. Something like the following would work:

```
<%=: vehicles | sort_by:'vehicleModel' | map:'vehicleModel' %>
```

Although it may not yield the same result you are looking for. In that case, you'll need to sort before hand in js. If the dataset of vehicle is quite large, I recommend sorting it right in the mongodb query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Akash..This does sort the data..Apology if this is a noobie question, but once I've sorted the array, can I assign this to a variable so I can take it as .length and pass it through each of my form elements?

Comment: @Aftab This is only a filter. If you sort things this way, you can't assign them. Best course of action would be to sort the array by using `[].sort()` before this line. You'll have much better control over that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akash.. It finally makes sense now.. I can run javascript natively inside the EJS tags.. Thats pretty neat..